# How can I make a script (unix) with this log file to run as simulator?

Tags: bash, awk

I have this log:

```
30-12-2022 23:24:32 : URI: p=2&pwr=0&noipcheck
30-12-2022 23:28:43 : URI: p=2&pwr=1110&noipcheck&debug
30-12-2022 23:28:51 : URI: p=2&pwr=0&noipcheck&debug
30-12-2022 23:31:57 : URI: p=2&pwr=2.200000
30-12-2022 23:50:02 : URI: p=2&pwr=0
31-12-2022 06:59:35 : URI: p=2&pwr=3
31-12-2022 07:04:35 : URI: p=2&pwr=0
31-12-2022 10:39:31 : URI: p=2&pwr=2.900000
31-12-2022 10:53:31 : URI: p=2&pwr=1507.900000
31-12-2022 10:53:36 : URI: p=2&pwr=1326.400000
31-12-2022 10:53:41 : URI: p=2&pwr=1410.200000
31-12-2022 10:53:46 : URI: p=2&pwr=2.900000
```

How can I now let write a script f.e.

`simulate <hostname> <mydate> <starttimestamp> <endtimestamp> <logfilename>`

where the date are filtered for `<mydate>` `<starttimestamp>` `<endtimestamp>` and the URI should be called with `<hostname>`.

I have problems in making the `sleep` as the second line needs to be read in advanced, so that I know the time difference.

f.e.  `simulate https://www.xxxx.at 31-12-2022 10:00:00  10:55:00 log.txt`

How can this be done in bash under unix?

It should then call `https://www.xxxx.at?<URI>` but with the timedelay after  the nearest `<starttimestamp>` between each call according the logtimes but now.

f.e:

```
     now: 
     `curl` "https://www.xxxx.at?p=2&pwr=2.900000"
     `sleep` timedifference [31-12-2022 10:53:31 - 31-12-2022 10:39:31]
     `curl` "https://www.xxxx.at?p=2&pwr=1507.900000"

      ...

     `sleep` timedifference [31-12-2022 10:53:46 - 31-12-2022 10:53:41] 
     `curl` "https://www.xxxx.at?p=2&pwr=2.900000"
```

Comment: Why the obsession with unreadable one liners? You're trying to get something to work, so take the time and effort to have it readable and understandable! (Optimisation should always be the last step - if it's considered at all - there's zero point having a beautifully optimised piece of code that doesn't work.)

Comment: Is this code to run on UNIX or Linux? Specifically do you have a version of `date` that can parse date/time strings and convert them to seconds?

Comment: `oneliner`s are the kiss of death for legible software. Posting one and asking for help with it is like cooking a meal and putting it through a blender before asking someone to taste it for feedback.

Comment: See also [the previous advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671432/how-can-i-calculate-the-mean-time-value-of-this-file-with-column-with-absolute-t#comment1266411_671432) you got about `oneliner`s.

Comment: And [this related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/544437/100397) from a range of responses about one-liners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could now do it in one awk script [named `mysim.awk`]:

```
    BEGIN { FS="- :" }
        {
        split($1,a,"[: -]")
        secs = mktime(a[3]" "a[2]" "a[1]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6])
        cmd[NR] = a[11]
        t[NR] = a[6] + 60 * (a[5] + 60 * a[4])
        dt[NR] =a[3]" "a[2]" "a[1]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6]
        }
    END {
        split(sdt,b,"[-: ]")
        split(edt,bb,"[-: ]")
        startsecs = mktime(b[3]" "b[2]" "b[1]" "b[4]" "b[5]" "b[6])
        endsecs   = mktime(bb[3]" "bb[2]" "bb[1]" "bb[4]" "bb[5]" "bb[6])
        print sdt"[->"startsecs"] bis "edt"[->"endsecs"]"
        for (c = 1; c <= NR-1; c++)
            {
            if ((mktime(dt[c]) >= startsecs) && (mktime(dt[c]) <= endsecs))
                {
                d = t[c+1] - t[c]
                if (d < 0) d += 86400
                h = d / 3600
                d %= 3600
                m = d / 60
                s = d % 60
                printf "sleep %02d ; %s%s \n",s,"curl \"https://xxxxx.at/sendsms.php?noresponse&noipcheck&nosms&debug&",cmd[c]"\""
                }
            }
        }
```

call from LINUX prompt with startdatetime and enddatetime f.e:

`awk -v sdt="31-12-2022 11:00:00" -v edt="31-12-2022 13:00:00"  -f mysim.awk mylog.txt`

or by a bash script (named `runsimulate.sh`] like this:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  # call f.e.  ./runsimulate.sh "02-01-2023 14:00:00" "02-01-2023 14:50:00" <logfilename>
  awk -f mysim.awk -v sdt="$1" -v edt="$2" $3
```